# Botbuilder, botframework

Tags: forms, botframework

Hi i have for exampe this form.

```
[Serializable]
public enum PassportFormType
{
    someEnum1,
    someEnum2,
    someEnum3,
}

[Serializable]
public class PassportForm
{
    [Prompt("Question text {||}")]
    public PassportFormType? Situace { get; set; }

    [Prompt("Question text {||}")]
    public int Count{ get; set; }
}
```

I want use custom validation for every enum type in my bot. 
I know I can use something like this

```
 .Field(nameof(Toppings),
        validate: async (state, value) =>
        {
           .
           .
           .
            return result;
        })
```

But its not solution for me, because i need use this again and again for every form.

How can i apply custom validation for every enum type?

Answer (score 0):

You can also provide a method, instead of a lambda:

```
async Task<ValidateResult> ValidateEnum(PassportForm state, object value)
{
    var result = new ValidateResult();
    result.IsValid = true;
    result.Value = value;

    //logic ...

    return result;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
.Field(nameof(PassportForm.Situace), validate: ValidateEnum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct. But my question is not correct.

I cant use validation because i want parse input text into value. But apply for every enum globaly.